# How to find specific ID with Jquery and perform action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 styles radio buttons with Enable / Disable, please check below..

```
<p class="switch-options">
  <label class="cb-enable selected" data-id="company_slogan_check">
    <span>Enable</span>
  </label>
  <label class="cb-disable" data-id="company_slogan_check">
   <span>Disable</span>
  </label>
  <input id="company_slogan_check" class="checkbox" type="hidden" value="0" name="company_slogan_check">
  <input id="company_slogan_check" class="checkbox main_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="company_slogan_check" checked="checked">
</p>
```

and I want to check if the "Enable" button is clicked I want to hide some DIV within the code. I am trying with the following code but nothing works..

```
jQuery('#company_slogan_check').click(function() {
    alert('sssss');
});
```

it doesnt even respond to the click.. can someone please help..

Comment: IDs _must_ be _unique_.

Comment: use `company_slogan_check` as a class value

Comment: Just a quick tip: you can write `$` instead of `jQuery`. Much shorter and easier ;).

Comment: And what elements do you want to hide, or are you just looking for an appropriate selector for the `<label>` elements (that you're using incorrectly, they're for associating text with a specific interactive `<form>` element, not for generic labelling of arbitrary elements)?

Answer (score 1):

`data-id` is not the same as an `id`, to which the css selector `#something` would apply to `id="something"`.

It would be easier to use `.switch-options input`

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, I did another workaround.. cheers

```
 if($(this).attr('data-id') == "company_slogan_check")
   alert('clicked');
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all ID's need to be unique as already mentioned..

second your not using radio buttons u use a checkbox..

and way not try the ":checked" ?

something like this:

```
$("#company_slogan_check").change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         // your function
      }
});
```

hope this was helpful